# How to change header background color in react based on location

Tags: reactjs, react-router, styled-components

How do I change my headers color based on what route/page I am on in my React project?
I have looked at `withRouter` but I am not sure how to use the example.
I just want to do something like if the route is not the Home component then change the background color of the header to blue.  Seems like it would be simple but can't figure it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `location` prop that is added to your component by connecting the component to the router via `withRouter`. From there you apply a conditional style based on which route path you are in.

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { withRouter } from 'react-router'

// A simple component that shows the pathname of the current location
class Header extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    match: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    location: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    history: PropTypes.object.isRequired
  }

  render() {
    const { match, location, history } = this.props

    const headerColor = location.pathname === 'home' ? { background: 'white'} : { background: 'blue' }
    return (
  <div style={headerColor}>You are now at {location.pathname}</div>
  )
}
}

// Create a new component that is "connected" (to borrow redux
// terminology) to the router.
const AdaptiveHeader = withRouter(Header)

export default AdaptiveHeader
```

For the above example I repurposed the code found [here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/withRouter.md).

Comment: This answer makes sense, however, when I try it myself I receive the typeError: cannot read property 'location' of undefined. Any tips?

Comment: @Jschriemer location should be read from `this.props` so first confirm you're doing this within a correctly configured React Component. If that's not the issue, I'd check to make sure `withRouter` still exposes a `location` value (and has not deprecated it since my initial answer).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `this.props.location` from `withRouter` to get the current pathname. Use that to check against `/home` or whatever your home page is, and then you can add a class to the Header that changes the color.

Comment: thanks for your help.  Alexei Darmin just made it click with me.