# How to change the header style based on specific route in react js?

Tags: reactjs

Basically I have a header like this,

```
function Header() {
  return (
    <div className="header">
      <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top ">
        <Link className="navbar-brand order-0 nav-link" to="/">
          DASA
        </Link>
      </nav>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Header;
```

Now, whenever I want this header beside home page. I want to its `fixed-top` property and also want to change its `background-color` which I have mentioned in the css file. How would I do it?
I also looked this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48525120/how-to-change-header-background-color-in-react-based-on-location) but could not figure out how to use it in my case?

Here is my app.js file.

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <Switch>
          {/* Men Category Route  */}
          <Route path="/men">
            <Header></Header>
            <Men></Men>
            <Footer></Footer>
          </Route>

          {/* Women Category Route  */}
          <Route path="/women">
            <Header></Header>
            <Women></Women>
            <Footer></Footer>
          </Route>
          {/* Women Category Route  */}
          <Route path="/kids">
            <Header></Header>
            <Kids></Kids>
            <Footer></Footer>
          </Route>
          {/* Authentication Route */}

          <Route path="/MenCategory">
            <MenProduct></MenProduct>
          </Route>
          <Route path="/signin">
            <Header></Header>
            <Authentication></Authentication>
            <Footer></Footer>
          </Route>
          {/* Home Route */}
          <Route path="/">
            <Header></Header>
            <Home></Home>
            <Footer></Footer>
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Right now, I am using `react-router-dom` for changing my route and all that. If any other information is need please let me know.

Comment: What are you using react-router ? And if so which version? We need more information about your route-management library.

Comment: I am using react-router-dom. I am preety new in this. What I know is I am using its latest version and if that's not the case I can update to its latest version. Or let me know if can do this with any other library

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're using the latest version of `react-router-dom` you can use the `useLocation()` hook. It will return a `location` object which has the property `pathname` that you can use to check the url and apply condition as needed.

Assuming your homepage is the root url `'/'`. In you `Header` component do this.

```js
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

function Header() {
  const { pathname } = useLocation();
 
  return (
    <div className="header" style={{ backgroundColor: pathname === '/' ? 'lightblue' : 'lightgreen' }}>
      <nav className={`navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light ${pathname === '/' ? 'fixed-top' : ''}`}>
        <Link className="navbar-brand order-0 nav-link" to="/">
          DASA
        </Link>
      </nav>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Header;
```

Comment: It should work. Here's a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-glitter-b4rcv). Try removing the 'none' value from `backgroundColor`. It isn't a valid CSS property so you might see no change in navbar styles. Use 'transparent' instead, which is valid.